# What is the Meaning of Mathematical Operator That There is a Bulge in the Lower Part of The Absolute Operator

Tags: notation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to figure out a question from the mathematical olympiads in 1998-1999.

[image: Problem 1 of Mathematical Olympiads]

What is the mathematical operator inside the red rectangle? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This denotes the floor function; there is also a related ceiling function.

- $\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left \lfloor #1 \right \rfloor}
  \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\left \lceil #1 \right \rceil}
  \floor{x}$ (the floor function) returns the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$
- $\ceil{x}$ (the ceiling function) returns the least integer greater than or equal to $x$.

Loosely, they are like "round down" and "round up" functions, respectively.

For instance,

- $\floor{1.4} = 1$
- $\floor{2.9} = 2$
- $\floor{-1.5} = -2$
- $\floor{-2.9} = -3$
- $\ceil{1.4} = 2$
- $\ceil{2.9} = 3$
- $\ceil{-1.5} = -1$
- $\ceil{-2.9} = -2$

More info is on [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)